# setinterval and load

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

This is a basic jquery problem I think, but it is very annoying. This is what I am doing:

1. load a href `class="tab"` lists file (external) from jquery
2. click on href and load from external file again
3. setinterval 1000 refresh the results (2) with load() method AGAIN

Question is: At refresh period, the value for name selector changes every 1 second (because of refresh), that I recently clicked the hrefs from #1.

```
$('a.tab').live('click',function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('name');
    //....
    setInterval(function(){
        $("div#timed").load('retriever.php', {"update":value} );
    } ,1000);//set interval
    //....
    $(this).undelegate('click');
});
```

Comment: @Blacklabel `question is: at refresh period, value for name selector changes every 1 second(because of refresh), that i recently clicked a hrefs from " 1)"`  In English class I was taught that this is a declarative sentence. Where is the interrogative? i.e What is your question?

Comment: When you say the name selector changes every second, are you changing it? Not sure what you mean here. Please provide a link to the content (for instance, the live with the problem or on http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is exactly your problem. `undelegate` is not for `live`. [`die`](http://api.jquery.com/die/) is for `live`.

Comment: The Problem is: At refresh period, the value for name selector changes every 1 second (because of refresh), that I recently clicked a hrefs from #1. i want only last clicked value i have made. not all of them, im not changing just randomly click the links but results are doubling 2 4 8 or more every time i click

Comment: @epascarello: I thought PHP was the only suicidal one. Now jQuery made JavaScript suicidal. Oh dear.

Comment: @BLACKLABEL - So you're getting a list but you want the one that was physically clicked on?

Comment: how to avoid doubling everytime i click .. for example. first click gets HELLO second click returns HELLO HELLO third click returns HELLOHELLOHELLO how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to cancel the other interval timers when you start a new one.

*edit* — oops hold on I'm fixing it ... ok thanks @kingjiv!!

```
$('a.tab').live('click',function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('name');
    var timers = $('body').data('timers') || {};
    //....
    for (var n in timers) clearInterval(timers[n]);

    timers[value] = setInterval(function(){
        $("div#timed").load('retriever.php', {"update":value} );
    } ,1000);//set interval
    //....
    $(this).undelegate('click');
    $('body').data('timers', timers);
});
```

As others have said, that "undelegate()" call is probably not doing what you think/want.

*edit again* — this could be done more intelligently; there really only needs to be *one* timer id stored on the body, of course.  I'm kind-of slow sometimes.

Comment: Yes, I think that's got to be what the OP is about.  If it isn't, well, he'll figure out he needs this anyway :-)

Comment: @Pointy - He seems to indicate that that's the case in his last comment. Easy enough mistake to make, I s'pose.

Comment: forget everythng, how can i avoid doubleor more resulting from a single click event . its about handler conflict or selector conflict smth

Comment: I think actually this will cause the content of `div#timed` to keep swapping back and forth if he clicks two different tabs.  If I'm understanding him (and it's very possible I'm not), he needs to clear the previous timer even if it was a different tab.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggest yet?  It's extremely difficult for us to understand what you're asking.  Did you check the jsfiddle that @Jared Farrish provided?

Comment: click a tab link > list soccer time datas > click one of them >then loads external php in main div> and countdowns the retrieved data. IF i repeat just like that countdown timer value thinks its not the only one it starts countdown with the previous visited data together, or more datas from previous visits. so countdown timer conflict.

Comment: Yes, ok, well my (fixed, thanks to @kingjiv) code keeps track of the timers and stops all of them every time it starts a new one.

Comment: there s no need to stop timer , it refreshes time with setinterval from db via load.

Comment: There is in fact a reason to stop the timer.  If you don't, then each click will start a *new* timer. You can start as many *separate* timers as you want to, and in your code that is what happens.  If you don't stop the timers, then they all will just keep going and going and going.

Comment: how can i stop it within a click bind ?

Comment: Well, you could keep the timer identifiers in an array, possibly stored in a jQuery ".data()" cell on the `<body>` tag.  Then, in the "click" handler, you could fetch the list of timer ids and iterate over them, calling "clearInterval()" for each one.  When you start a new timer, store the id back in the data object and save it.

Comment: page shows only one timer when user attempts to switch page to click another tab , i think a click bind to clearinterval will be enough.

Comment: Yes probably - there's no need for an array actually.